# JSF page accessible without the folder name in path

Tags: jsf, url, rbac

I'm trying to restrict access to JSF pages based on user roles. I saw lot of examples using filter. So I'm good there. I tried to put my xhtml files within "secured" folder under webapp folder that I need to protect. one of the xhtml file that I need to allow access to "admin" users is newAuth.xhtml and I have it inside the "secured" folder. On my menu page for the link which accesses "newAuth.xhtml" I gave the path including the "secured" folder. So the page comes up with url "server:port/signer/secured/newAuth.xhtml". Now when I tried to remove the "secured" path from the browser url, it still displays this page. I have the below mapping for FacesServlet in my web.xml.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm not sure how to protect the page from displaying when the path /secured is removed from the url.

**UPDATE:**

Leo, may be I should have explained my problem better in first place.
I wanted to implement the security filter based on the path in the url. If the url has /secured and if the user is non-admin then I would redirect them to some default page. This was my idea and so I placed all the restricted xhtml to the secured folder under webapp folder. For example newAuth.xhtml is a restricted xhtml page which only admin should have access. This page was accessible by the below url.

"protocol://server:port/signer/secured/newAuth.xhtml"

Then I tried to remove the /secured from the url, but the same page displays. Somehow the JSF was able to find the xhtml even without the /secured path. This behaviour will go against my security filter logic which will look for /secured in the url path.

Comment: this servlet-mapping rule just tells the container that requests to xhtml files must be processed as JSF pages. To restrict access given a path, you can try using a filter http://uaihebert.com/user-authentication-filterservlet/

Comment: Leo, I did not show the filter code here. My filter checks for the url and if the path has /secured and if user role is not admin, then redirect them to default page. But my problem is the same page is accessible without /secured path also.

Comment: if your question has everything we need to reproduce your problem, than it's a win-win situation I guess :-)

Comment: did you configure a security-constraint, a security-role and a login-config on your web.xml? when i protect my applications i usually do that. also we have to configure the server for that to work.